# SWT - Adding a Image to a Button in a table - tableViewer

Tags: java, image, swt

I would like to add a image to a button in my table.  The table is displayed in my main GUI.  I am using a `TableViewer` to display the table.

```
private void createTableViewer(Composite parent) {

  viewer = new AplotDataTableViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER|SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
  viewer.setInput(AplotDataModel.getInstance().getArrayData());
```

}

`AplotDataTableViewer` is a separate class. The constructor for `AplotDataTableViewer` takes in the composite and Style.

So when I try to add a image in the `AplotDataTableViewer` class, it gives me a error on the `Display` variable.  I think it is because  Image requires a Display.

```
Image image = new Image(display, String);
```

I am not sure what it is needing for display?  If it is needing the display from the main GUI, how do I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use:

```
Image image = new Image(Display.getDefault(), "path/to/image.png");
```

Or use `Display.getCurrent()` instead.

For more details, here is a good tutorial about SWT `Image`s:

[Taking a look at SWT Images](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what error you are getting. I am guessing it might be "Invalid Thread access" as you are accessing UI objects from non-UI thread.

You can create images by referring to the link given by Baz. If your plugin has Activator, just check for  `public static ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor(String path)` here path starts with ex: /icons/image.png. User `ImageDescriptor.createImage(true)` will give the actual image that you are looking for. Keep track of the images in a cache before creating new one from imagedescriptor.

Setting Image on Button, check for documentation. Few platforms won't support setting both image and text.